# Reverse Routing Play with POST payload

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, typesafe

I have the following use case where I wanted to use reverse routing.

```
    Project 
      com.xyz.controllers
       --> Hello.java
          -- Result sayHello();
       --> HelloWrapper.java
          -- wrapSayHello()
```

Following is the Routes file :

```
     POST           /hello                 @com.xyz.controllers.Hello.sayHello()
```

sayHello expects a JSON body in the request to it and reads of it using request().body().asJson()

How can one use reverse routing and have some payload sent in the request.
I see that using reverse routing in wrapSayHello() method, 
I can call the method like this

```
     routes.Hello.sayHello()
```

but I have no much clue on how to send in some json in the request body as the original method expects

Any thoughts would be helpful ..

Comment: Anything you found on this? @hackmabrain

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, still, this could be useful for some other people.

```
jsRoutes.controllers.Hello.sayHello().ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify( jsonObject ),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success : function(data) {
    },
    error : function(error) {
        console.log("error: " + error);
    }
});
```

The controller method:

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public Result sayHello() {
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    logger.debug(" JSON Stuff received : " + Json.prettyPrint(json));
    return ok();
}
```